# How to design an economic index?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, computational-statistics, macroeconomics

I'm designing a linear economic index:

$I_{t}=W_{1} X_{t_{1}}+W_{2}X_{t_{2}}+W_{3}X_{t_{3}}$

where $W_{1}$ to $W_{3}$ are weights of inputs ($X_{t_{1}}$ to $X_{t_{3}}$) and $I_{t}$ is the final index for a city. $X_{t_{1}}$ to $X_{t_{3}}$ are indexes based on a specific city so all indexes are regardless of units. My questions:

1. How can I calculate suitability of an index? (Statistical and mathematical methods)
2. In this version of creating index we found weights based on interviews. Is there another way to calculate weights (based on available data or other techniques)?
3. Should I check non-linear forms or other model specifications?
4. What can I do to have better index? (Other statistical tests etc.)

Comment: You really do have to define _suitability_ to get good answers here. Otherwise the success of any data reduction is success at a given purpose, i.e. why do you want to do this?

Comment: Index specification, significant inputs an suitable weights.

Comment: Sorry, but "significant" and "suitable" don't answer the question here.

Comment: I'm searching to find main steam (statistically tests and procedures) to have a final better index.

Comment: It's the same broad question and without trying to be flippant or unsupportive I can't think of a better concise answer. I can think of fuller answers, but they would all be of the flavour: If you want to do this, then that advice. If you want to do something else, then different advice.  What you can always do, however, is measure how much information is lost by compressing from three measures to one. Why do you (think you) need one? That's often primitive thinking statistically.

Comment: So is any measurement technique to calculate "information is lost by compressing"? or other related techniques to do these tests?

Comment: Principal component analysis, to start with. Or just looking at the correlation matrix.

Comment: @NickCox isn't this a lot like the original problem factor analysis is intended to solve?

Comment: @ssdecontrol Sure. It's a matter of tribal habits and attitudes. I regard factor analysis as usually practised as a dubious variant of PCA, but precisely the opposite attitude is also common in statistical science.

Comment: So as discussed we can use PCA to convert n inputs to 1 inputs (index) (creating an index using PCA) or we are using it for another analysis?

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of papers that provide significant detail on the methodology behind various economic indices.

Examples/Case Studies

[Constructing socio-economic status indices: how to use principal components analysis](http://heapol.oxfordjournals.org/content/21/6/459.full)

[The Composite Index of Leading Economic Indicators](http://www.nber.org/papers/w8430.pdf)

[Creating a sustainable national index for social, environmental and economic productivity](http://www.wcps.info/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/SEE_index_-_inline-Figs.pdf)

[Defining Economic Freedom](http://www.heritage.org/index/book/chapter-2)

[New Economic Indexes for Las Vegas, Nevada](http://cber.unlv.edu/reports/SoNVEconomicIndexes.pdf)